# Trying to uninstall a package. Uninstall status failed

Tags: uninstall

I am trying to uninstall a package, but the uninstall status fails every time and I don't know what to do as there is no feedback on the page to why the uninstall has failed.

Can anyone advise on why this is happening?

```
Uninstalled Packages

Del Sage Live Wave (Version Name May 2017)      04/01/2020 14:57    Uninstall Failed    02/01/2020 14:57
Del Sage Live Wave (Version Name May 2017)      04/01/2020 14:43    Uninstall Failed    02/01/2020 14:43
Del Sage Live Wave (Version Name May 2017)      04/01/2020 14:39    Uninstall Failed    02/01/2020 14:39
```

I have an error now.

```
Flatted_Ledger_Item_Tags could not be removed during uninstall.
insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
```

Update:

Turns out according to Salesforce Support I need a license to uninstall the package, which has expired. Need to contact my AE to provide a new one.

Comment: Since it is a managed package, have you checked with the vendor's support?

Comment: It's an unmanaged package, with little information about the vendor. It just seems to be a analytics package made by sage.

Comment: Often, packages fail to uninstall because their components are referenced by other metadata - perhaps in this case Reports or Dashboards?

Comment: There are quite a ton of sage reports and dashboards. You're probably right.

Comment: @AlexanderAtkinsoon  "I have an error now." - how did you get that error?  I'm having the same issue and cannot find any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove it from the Installed Packages screen, you normally see the components that are causing the errors. But in my experience, the typically issues I see are

1. Custom Buttons on your page layouts
2. Your custom Reports or Dashboards in folders in the package (so removing the package would remove the location of that report - so you need to move the report)
3. Reference to fields in package in Formula Fields or Duplicate Rules or Sharing Rule Criteria
4. References to fields in your workflow rules/actions
5. Records using Record Types in the packages

Comment: I've came back to some error emails. Package: Sage Live Wave (04t0Y0000018OBJ) Error Number: 1114986291-139119 (677098974)

Flatted_Ledger_Item_Tags could not be removed during uninstall.
insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Comment: Sounds like you created some local tags for that managed object - I'd remove them first and see what happens (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tag_search.htm&type=5)

Comment: possibly related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/354623/2602

Answer (score 0):

In my org we had that same problem. We solve it using the user with the "Einstein Analytics Platform" license to uninstall de package.