# Deleted custom fields not hard deleted after 15 days

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-field

I checked the `Deleted Fields` section of one of our custom objects.

In there it says;

> Salesforce starts to hard delete these fields after 15 days.

but in that list, I am seeing fields that we have deleted more than two months ago. I am quite sure about the timeline because we took a task to delete obsolete fields and its resolved date is June.

Any idea what could be the reason for those fields to not got hard deleted?

Comment: Have you initiated a hard delete manually (delete from the Deleted FIelds list)? If not, I'd do that first if you just want the data gone. Aside from that, if it's been that long, you should log a case with Support.

Comment: if when you Erase, you get Insufficient privileges - check out this [workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/354968/2602)

Comment: I am able to hard delete (Erase) manually and deleted a couple of fields with that. For the other 100+, I created a case. I will update here if I get any answer to "why it is happening" part. Thanks for the suggestions ^^

Comment: an interesting experiment to do in your org with the workaround _disabled_ is to create a new custom field, then delete it, then erase it.  In some of my orgs, the delete/erase step gets insufficient privileges - not all orgs though and seemingly related to the time when they were last refreshed from PROD (hypothesis)

Comment: _Adding a comment just in case someone stumbles on this._ After _lots of_ back-and-forths with the support, I just gave up. Getting the same 3-4 responses from them was only time-wasting for everybody, so I still have no idea why hard delete is not triggered in our orgs.