# Getting Insufficient Privileges Error Trying to Rename Custom Object API Name

Tags: apex, custom-object, error, administration

I'm attempting to rename the API name of a custom object, however when I change the name and click save I get the following error:

```
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Click here to return to the previous page.
```

I've already commented out all references in code and have a System Administrator profile that has full access to the object. So I'm not sure why I would be getting this error. I also logged in as other System Admin users and they all had the same error.

Any thoughts why I can't change the API name of a custom object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some other people have had similar issues, there is a workaround outlined in this article but it may no longer work - worth a try though! [Deleting (or Renaming) Custom Metadata Object / Custom Object yields Insufficient Privileges](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354623/deleting-or-renaming-custom-metadata-object-custom-object-yields-insufficien)